# How to prove $((p \to q ) \to ((R \to p) \to (R \to q)))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Can anyone please tell me how to prove $((p \to q ) \to ((R \to p) \to (R \to q)))$ ?

My Attempt : I will show that when $(p \to q ) $ is true , $((R \to p) \to (R \to q))$ is also true. So I have to show when $q$ is true , $((R \to p) \to (R \to q))$ is also true and when $p , q$ are both false , $((R \to p) \to (R \to q))$ is also false .

Can anyone please check my attempt?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you wrote R instead of r?. What kind of derivation do you need? because you can prove it using the laws of equivalence, natural deduction, truth tables, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you've written isn't quite correct.  If $R$ is false, then $((R \rightarrow p) \rightarrow (R \rightarrow q))$ is true.  We'll write $\sigma = (p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow ((R \rightarrow p) \rightarrow (R \rightarrow q))$.

If $R$ is false, then both $R \rightarrow p$ and $R \rightarrow q$ are vacuously true, so $((R \rightarrow p) \rightarrow (R \rightarrow q))$ is also true, and $\sigma$ is true because its conclusion is true.

If $R$ is true and $R \rightarrow p$ is false, then $((R \rightarrow p) \rightarrow (R \rightarrow q))$ is true because the premise is false, and again, $\sigma$ is true because irs conclusion is true.

If $p \rightarrow q$ is false, then $\sigma$ is true because its premise is false.

Finally, if $R \rightarrow p, p \rightarrow q,$  and $R$ are all true, then $p$ is true (because $R$ and $R \rightarrow p$ are true), so $q$ is true (because $p$ and $p \rightarrow q$ are true), which means $R \rightarrow q$ is true (because $R$ and $q$ are both true), so $((R \rightarrow p) \rightarrow (R \rightarrow q))$ is true and $\sigma$ is true.

Comment: I did not understand where I went wrong. @Robert Shore

Comment: I learnt that  $B$ is false or $A , B$ are also false  iff $A \to B$ is true. I just applied this in my attempt. Can you please indicate where I went wrong. @Robert Shore

Comment: @sani If $p$ and $q$ are both false, then $p \rightarrow q$ is true, so $(R \rightarrow p) \rightarrow (R \rightarrow q)$ needs to be true, not false.  Your comment above is wrong.  Either $A$ is false or $B$ is true $\iff A \rightarrow B$.

Answer (score 0):

The part where you said

> I have to show when $q$ is true , $((R \to p) \to (R \to q))$ is also true

is correct.  But the part where you said

> and when $p , q$ are both false , $((R \to p) \to (R \to q))$ is also false

is not correct.   If $p$ and $q$ are both false, then $p\to q$ is true, and if $p\to q$ is true, then so is $((R \to p) \to (R \to q))$.

Answer (score 0):

1. $p\rightarrow q$ (assumption)
2. $R\rightarrow p$ (assumption)
3. $\sim(R\rightarrow q)$ (assumption)
4. $\sim(\sim R\vee q)$ (equivalence of $R\rightarrow q$ and $\sim R\vee q$, 3)
5. ($\sim\sim R)\wedge\sim q$ (De Morgan law, 4)
6. $R\wedge\sim q$ (equivalence of $R$ and $\sim\sim R$, double
   negation, 5)
7. $R$ (simplification, 6)
8. $p$ (MP, 2 and 7)
9. $q$ (MP, 1 and 8)
10. $\sim q$ (simplification, 6)
11. $q\wedge\sim q$ (conjunction, 9 and 10)
12. $\sim\sim(R\rightarrow q)$ (reductio ad absurdum, 11, now lines
    3 to 11 all becomes invalid and are deleted)
13. $R\rightarrow q$ (double negation, 12)
14. $(R\rightarrow p)\rightarrow(R\rightarrow q)$ (rule of conditional
    proof, 2 and 13, now lines 2 to 13 all becomes invalid and are deleted)
15. $(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow\left((R\rightarrow p)\rightarrow(R\rightarrow q)\right)$
    (rule of conditional proof, 1 and 14, now lines 1 to 14 becomes invalid
    and are deleted)

Comment: Can you please check my attempt? I do not want to get into so much deep. @Danny Pak-Keung Chan

Comment: You may need to learn some inference rules before you can prove the proposition formally.

Comment: Without using these can I not do ? Can you please tell me whether my attempt has any flaw or not ? @Danny Pak-Keung Chan

Comment: It is impossible to prove a complicated proposition without knowledge about inference rules. If one does not know inference rules, he/she can easily commit mistakes without realizing it.